# Camera functionality is not working with cordova.js/ camera.js

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, camera

Iam working on camera functionality with cordova in my javascript project. I used cordova.js and camera.js files in my project. But When I call getPicture() function of camera.js, it is not working in my device. You can find the below code which I tried in my html. Please help me in acheiving this. Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
    <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script src="Camera.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script language="javascript">

     var pictureSource;
     var destinationType;

         document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
   pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
   destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
  }

  function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
   var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
   smallImage.style.display = 'block';
   smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
  }

  function capturePhoto() {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
  }


  function getPhoto(source) {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
  }
  function onFail(message) {
   alert('Failed because: ' + message);
  }
    
    
    document.getElementById('cam1').innerHTML='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="capturePhoto()"><img src="../images/camera_up.gif" alt="img" width="23" height="20" border="0" id="smallImage" /></a>';
    </script>
```

Comment: What `Log Cat` is showing ? any Message ?

Comment: Maybe `DATA_URL` type is eating up too much memory and OS interrupts your script? Try using `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` type instead and see if it works...

Comment: @jaydroider I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined in Log Cat

Comment: @Uzbekjon I tried with ur code, but still not working.

Comment: So may be the problem is in installing the camera plugins.

Comment: I added the plugin, I checked in manifest file and config file. Everything is correct.

Comment: Something should be missing with error which you get. and it's sure with plugins.

Comment: @jaydroider I did this alert(navigator.camera) inside capturePhoto() function. It is giving me undefined.

Comment: I would like to suggest you to install media and media capture plugins instead of camera try with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the plugin via command console, locate your project and then use this commands.

- Cordova version 5.0 +

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

- Older version

> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera

This commands automatically add references in your config.xml

Remove this reference:

```
<script src="Camera.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: also ake sure that `cordova_plugins.js` loads correctly. I had an issue with that yesterday.